# moving emails from google apps to microsoft exchange 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, g-suite, exchange-migration

We have our emails hosted with Google Apps at the moment and would like to migrate to an in-house solution with Microsoft Exchange 2010 server. How would i go about migrating all the emails from Google Apps to MS Exchange 2010?

Is there an option in Exchange to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any automated tool; however, if you connect Outlook to the new Exchange account and the Google Apps account through IMAP, you can drag/drop emails and folders from the old Google Apps to the new Exchange accounts.

You could probably write an Outlook Macro to do this automatically, but I have not delt with VSTO or Outlook Macros, so thats just speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of such an option that is built into Exchange. I would look into using something like [imapsync](http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync/) to copy/sync mail from Google into Exchange.