# Moving email from google

Tags: email, gmail, thunderbird

We purchased a business and the previous owner had an email with our domain name along with info and such and it was hosted by google. I'm paying for info@olddomain.com and want to move to my email server but can't move without moving hers.

The catch is that she has a bunch of historical emails that she wants to keep and when I move the email she will lose the previous emails even though I have no objection to her keeping the address.

So, how to resolve and move this account to bluehost?

I found this and it wasn't a big help: [moving emails from google apps to microsoft exchange 2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/284623/moving-emails-from-google-apps-to-microsoft-exchange-2010). I'm thinking that I have her install Thunderbird and have it sync with her mail folder and now all the emails are in thunderbird.

But now what?

So here's my current thought. I add her gmail account and her account with my domain to thunderbird and sync them both as it looks like Thunderbird can work with gmail. Then I create a new folder under her gmail account. Then I drag all of her old emails into the new folder and re-sync and then shut down thunderbird. Now i migrate the domain to bluehost as planned and all of her stuff is in her gmail account.

Opinions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, it all just depends on what your desired end state is.

If Thunderbird is your goal then I'd recommend checking out the [data export tools from Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10016932?hl=en). Email should be exported in MBOX format, which you can then [import into Thunderbird](https://www.sysinfotools.com/blog/import-mbox-file-in-thunderbird/) for viewing.

If you'd rather migrate them from the Google Workspace account to a personal Gmail account [it can be done, too](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289).

Comment: Why would I import it into Thunderbird? That's not a goal.

Comment: @Thom It isn't? You say: "I'm thinking that I have her install Thunderbird and have it sync with her mail folder and now all the emails are in thunderbird."

Comment: @Mast as a way to move email. The goal is simply to move the email.

Comment: The link to sysinfotools is dubious; they have a history of spamming.